# how can we find streaming audio duration before playing in iphone in AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to add timer in AVAudioPlayer with UISlider.But problem is that i want to play a url streaming audio(not a source file) and i dont know how to find duration of that audio file before playing and add UISlider with the time interval.I have seen many tutorials but no one works .Please guide me for adding timer with UISlider.